# 9gag parse json

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I want to pick a random picture from:

> http://9gag.com/top/all/index/page/1?view=json

To display it properly i need to know the size of this image.

I use YQL to put the result of this json in a variable (called **source**).

I replace https with http and delete each backslash.

```
var it = $.parseJSON(source);
var total = it.count-1;
var random = Math.floor((Math.random()*total)+0);     
var gagurl = it.items[random];
var gagurldecode = gagurl.replace('\\','');
gagurldecode = gagurldecode.replace('https','http'); //here is the url of the image
```

But i can't retrieve the size of this image .

```
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = gagurldecode;
```

alert(img.height); returns nothing.

If i replace

```
img.src = gagurldecode;
```

with

```
img.src = 'http://d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net/photo/1777377_460s.jpg';
```

it works.

**What I do wrong?**
PS:Sorry for my english!

Comment: I hope you're either getting paid or doing some not beneficial for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line is unnecessary because the slashes are escaped when the JSON is parsed:

```
var gagurldecode = gagurl.replace('\\','');
```

For your actual problem, the `height` and `width` are not populated until after the image has been downloaded and examined.  This is done asynchronously if the browser has not seen the image (in the `onload` event handler) but may be done synchronously if retrieving from the cache like in your hard coded example:

```
img.onload = function() {
    alert(img.height);
}
```

This will work every time.

Answer (score 0):

why are you doing the replace calls? 
This is not needed, because the slashes will be unescaped for you after the string is parsed into json. (moreover, your replace calls are not replaceAll)

try this:

```
//str is going to be the json you get from that url
var str = '{"items":["http:\/\/d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net\/photo\/5373376_460s.jpg","http:\/\/d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net\/photo\/2899638_460s_v1.jpg","http:\/\/d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net\/photo\/3196367_460s.jpg","http:\/\/d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net\/photo\/1777377_460s.jpg","http:\/\/d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net\/photo\/3233576_460s.jpg","http:\/\/d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net\/photo\/3101249_460s.jpg","http:\/\/d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net\/photo\/3279498_460s.jpg","http:\/\/d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net\/photo\/2487961_460s.jpg","http:\/\/d24w6bsrhbeh9d.cloudfront.net\/photo\/2693569_460s.jpg"],"layout":"list","count":9}'
var obj = JSON.parse(str);
var src = obj.items[~~(Math.random() * (obj.items.length - 1))];
img.src = src;
```

Comment: What's `replaceAll`? [Couldn't find it on google...](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+replaceAll)

Comment: there is no replaceAll (in js). people usually think that replace is replaceAll when used as he did above